# SyntaxError unexpected end of json input Node Js

Tags: node.js, json, api, syntax-error, gzip

I'm trying to retrieve data from Keepa using express js and HTTP module,
Keepa sending all data as gzip.
I was challenged to get the data properly and I got a previous error-Unexpected token in JSON at position 0,
So I have installed 'decompress-response' module which resolved this issue but now I'm getting half of the JSON data and then a new syntax error appears - **unexpected end of json input Node Js**

I'm trying to figure what am I missing here.. hope you can help me.

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const decompressResponse = require("decompress-response");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

console.log(req.body.asinId);
const query = req.body.asinId;
const apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
const url = "https://api.keepa.com/product?key="+ apiKey +"&domain=1&asin="+ query;

https.get(url, function(response){
response = decompressResponse(response);
console.log(response.statusCode);
console.log(response.headers);
var data;
response.on("data", function(chunk) {
if (!data) {
  data = chunk;
} else {
  data += chunk;
}
 const asinData = JSON.parse(data);
 
  console.log(asinData);
  res.send();
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to print the response before "response = decompressResponse(response);". And let me know what you get there.

Comment: Hey , i have got - 
Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Comment: Looks like the response format is not same what you are expecting. Try making request using postman and see what response you are getting back. Also the error could be in this line "const asinData = JSON.parse(data);",, try to comment it out and console log "data" variable. It should be a valid json string.

Comment: hey thank you, I commented the JSON.parse line - I got now data but it's a weird JSON format that any JSON handler extension cannot read .... I think that something is still missing but it's really close to being the right results...

Comment: if possible, can you please share the data ? I would like to have a look.